multiple locks in Python
In my Python3.12 code I have three threads in which the first thread T1 is a consumer, the second thread T2 is a producer, and the third thread T3 is a logger.
However, I have three additional variables N, P, and Limits in T2 manipulated by a function which are also manipulated by a another function in T3 as well.
The question is what is the right approach in terms of number of locks and their manipulation in such a situation ? In other terms, do I need to have one ore more lock(s) to handle the 3 variables ?
I have tried using one lock (Lock) but did not get the expected result. I am not sure if the following is accurate.
Basically, thread T2 has to call the following method.
with lock:
    def update_variables_1(n=N, p=P, limits=Limits):
        n+= power(n, 2)
        p+= n
        limits = (n+p) / 2  

while thread T3 has to call this one.
with Lock:
    def update_variables_2(n=N, p=P, limits=Limits):
        n-= power(n, 2)
        p-= n
        limits = (n-p) / 2  

So, I ended up in using a Lock before calling update_variables_1() and update_variables_2() in the respective threads.

Yes, just have one lock per entity (your three variables could count as one entity). Its just that if your code allows both locks to be taken, then they should always be taken in the same order: first L1 then L2 or the other way round, but pick your order and stick to it.

@quamrana, thank you for your reply. I will go with that and see if the result is correct. Do I have to pass them as arguments or use them as global variables ?

Your locks should sit alongside the variables that they protect. You already have functions which access variables, so they should be able to access the locks in the same way.

Is there a specific reason why you're using a lock for the queue? Assuming it's a queue.Queue object or similar, they are already thread-safe and have their own internal locks. If it's reasonable to share some simplified code, maybe some better advice could be offered.

@sytech, that is a good point. I forgot this detail. I will not use a lock for the Queue then. I have put the two methods I am calling which require the Lock.

I see you have updated your question to include some code. Unfortunately these functions seem to do nothing. What is it that you think these two threads will change about "variables V1, V2, and V3"?

@quamrana, I apologize, I did not change the name of the variables accordingly. Now, the variables are N, P, and Limits.

Changing the names has no effect. Your functions still do nothing. Also there is no evidence that they are called. Please post your real code.

quamrana said in a comment,

Have one lock per entity (your three variables could count as one entity.)

How you decide that is, you consider whether or not there is some important relationship between the variables. A single thread that needs to change several variables can only do it one variable at a time. You've got to ask yourself, if Thread A was paused by the OS,* half-way through updating some set of variables, and Thread B looks at those variables while A was paused, could it be bad? Could Thread B see something that it wasn't supposed to see? Something that doesn't make sense? If so, then the set of variables is one of those "entities" that quamrana was talking about, and it needs to be protected by a lock.
It's OK to have one lock that protects more than one "entity." That's the essence of "coarse grained locking." What doesn't work is if you use locks inconsistently. What I mean there is, Suppose that some variable V belongs to entity E1. Any time any thread ever accesses V you'll need it to lock L1.  If the same variable V also is a member of some other entity, E2, (not a great idea, but it happens), then you're going to need a lock, L2 for the other entity, and any time you do anything that could change V, you're going to need to lock both locks. In my personal opinion, if you ever get to that point, you'll be better off if you do it the "coarse" way, and protect both entities with the same lock.

* "Paused by the OS" is a thing that happens all the time in multi-threaded programs (and, in single-threaded programs too.)
